# How to clean the Array after write some information

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pipe

I first declare a pointer array

```
int q,k;
char ***schArray;
schArray = malloc(sizeof(char**)*1000);
    for(q = 0; q < 1000; q++) {
        schArray[q] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*100);
        for(k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
            schArray[q][k] = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
        }
    }

char buf[80]={0};
```

Then I read some data from pipe which put it in the buf and copy it to the pointer Array

```
strcpy(schArray[commandnum][0], buf);
```

After that, I want to clean the content of Pointer Array. I use the following code.

```
schArray[commandnum][0]=NULL;
```

After that, I cannot write any data to schArray[commandnum][0] by the code

```
strcpy(schArray[commandnum][0], buf);
```

Is there any mistake in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to set the first character of an allocated string to `'\0'`.  You'd do this using

```
schArray[commandnum][0][0] = '\0';
```

Your current code replaces (and leaks) the pointer to the buffer allocated by `malloc(sizeof(char)*100)`

As an aside, and before anyone pulls me up on it, note that `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 so the `malloc` can be simplified to `malloc(100)`.

Comment: Sorry about the same question, I still cannot write new data after using the command priorityArray[counter_internal][0]='\0'; It show no response when I try to write some new data in that Array.

Comment: Is the type of `priorityArray` `char***`? If it is, you need to do `priorityArray[counter_internal][0][0]='\0';` if you want to change the first character of an allocated buffer.  The version in your comment over-writes part of the pointer to the allocated buffer.